# Can I use multiple beforeCommit from multiple webfilters and how to control the order of execution?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have multiple WebFilters (Webflux Webfilter not the traditional spring MVC filter), each needs to execute some logic before response commit. Can i use multiple beforeCommit ?

for example, in filter 1 have have

```
  exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
      a();
  });
```

in filter 2 I have

```
 exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
  b();
});
```

Will both a and b get executed before response commit? If so can I control order? (I want a execute first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the `beforeCommit` will be the order of the filters inside which they are specified.

eg.
If have a `TenancyContextFilter` of Order -1:

```
@Component
@Order(-1)
public class TenancyContextFilter implements WebFilter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenancyContextFilter.class);

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    //..some logic...
    exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
      return Mono.subscriberContext().doOnNext(ctx -> {
        System.out.println("Executing before commit for TenancyContextFilter");
      }).then();
    });
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }

}
```

and a `ScopeCheckFilter` of order -2,

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class ScopeCheckFilter implements WebFilter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScopeCheckFilter.class);

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    //some logic...
    exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
      return Mono.subscriberContext().doOnNext(ctx -> {
        System.out.println("Executing before commit for ScopeCheckFilter");
      }).then();
    });
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

Then the `ScopeCheckFilter` executes before `TenancyContextFilter` , so as their beforeCommit logic.

Thus the logs I get, when I execute, are:

```
2020-07-23 13:04:09.345  INFO c.b.e.i.ImageServiceApplication          :[        ] Starting ImageServiceApplication on in1-1025453mbp with PID 98071 (/Users/Abhi/codes/image-service/out/production/classes started by 1025453 in /Users/Abhi/codes/image-service)
2020-07-23 13:04:09.347  INFO c.b.e.i.ImageServiceApplication          :[        ] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-23 13:04:10.606  INFO o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      :[        ] Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-07-23 13:04:10.805  INFO o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  :[        ] Netty started on port(s): 8080
2020-07-23 13:04:10.825  INFO c.b.e.i.ImageServiceApplication          :[        ] Started ImageServiceApplication in 1.741 seconds (JVM running for 2.309)
2020-07-23 13:04:14.519  INFO c.b.e.i.controller.ImageController       :[tenant1] Request received to generate SAS Token
2020-07-23 13:04:15.714  INFO c.b.e.i.s.a.AzureImageStorageService     :[tenant1] Container exists
2020-07-23 13:04:15.715  INFO c.b.e.i.s.a.AzureImageStorageService     :[tenant1] Generating SAS Token
Executing before commit for ScopeCheckFilter
Executing before commit for TenancyContextFilter
```

And if you have added your filters in the `WebSecurity Filter Chain`, then, also, it will be same as the order in which you add those filters.

eg. Below I am adding the `ScopeCheckFilter` first to the `SecurityWebFilterChain`.

```
  @Bean
  SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        //..some logic....
        ;

    http.addFilterAfter(new ScopeCheckFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);
    http.addFilterAfter(new TenancyContextFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);

    return http.build();
  }
```